# Prefix value to a field form value in angular reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using matPrefix to prefix value to Phone Number.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{ 'MOBILE' | translate }}</mat-label>
    <span matPrefix>05&nbsp;</span>
    <input type="tel" matInput placeholder="67000020" maxlength="8" dir="ltr" formControlName="MobileNo">
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  MobileNo: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\d{8}$/)])]
});
```

I want prefix to be part of the Phone number value sent from the form.

Right now I am appending '05' while saving the number and removing the prefix while editing the form.

I want to use the mobile number field in multiple forms.I think seperate component for it seems to be an overkill.

Is there any better way to prefix value in a form field instead of appending/slicing prefix value while saving/editing?

Comment: I don't think a component is an overkill, I can't think of any other nice way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to add separate component if u do more customizing things there. But if u want to try another thing u can try below ng-template thing there

```
<ng-template #inputWithPrefix >
       <mat-label>{{ 'MOBILE' | translate }}</mat-label>
       <span matPrefix>05&nbsp;</span>
       <input type="tel" matInput placeholder="67000020" maxlength="8" dir="ltr" formControlName="MobileNo">
</ng-template>
```

then u can use this like below

```
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="inputWithPrefix"></ng-template>
```

you can pass parameter as well here like below

```
 <ng-template #inputWithPrefix let-placeHolderVal="placeHolderVal">
  {{ placeHolderVal }}
 </ng-template>
```

follow this URL to get more details about ng-template and template-outlet https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/